# Can't install certain Steam games on ExFAT hard drive

Tags: steam, hard-drive

I was trying to install BioShock Infinite on my external hard drive, but Steam said it couldn't use my hard drive because it uses the FAT32 filesystem which I'm assuming is because it has a 4GB per file limit. But since I'm using ExFAT which doesn't have this limitation, this shouldn't be an issue. I read an answer to a similar question with the answer being that Steam checks for a 'FAT' name string for the volume format and since ExFAT has FAT in the name, it picks it up as FAT32. The same answer also suggested that I could possibly inject a .dll file into it, which seemed a bit shady but I don't know.

Does anyone know a way I can get around this limitation? In addition, the answer I referenced before can be found [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306621/how-can-i-fool-steam-to-think-my-exfat-drive-is-ntfs/318832#318832)